# Convert time in seconds from the Epoch to day of the year?

Tags: c++, time, epoch

I have a file filled with data, one column of which is seconds from the Epoch. For reference, an example value looks like this:

> 1498493536984926976

I need to convert it into a day of the year. What I have so far is this piece of code, which uses [this reference](https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/c) to convert the date into a normal readable struct and then strftime to pull the day of the year from the struct:

```
time_t rawtime = stol(exploded_line[2]);
std::cout << rawtime << std::endl;
struct tm date; 
date = *localtime( &rawtime );
char *buffer;
std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
strftime (buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%j",&date);
```

However, this code `SegFaults` on the `strftime` line! I have no idea what is causing this. I have tried initializing `buffer` as

```
char buffer[80];
```

and various other declarations but nothing seems to work. I've also tried ditching the buffer entirely and just using a `std::string`; that hasn't worked either.

Also, I am not partial to this method. If anyone else has a better method of getting the day of the year from an Epoch time, I will totally implement it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'll be honest here, I'd probably go find a date time library and just include that in the file because that's a headache I don't want.

Comment: @Jhecht I wish haha. This is not my dataset, it was taken over a month ago. I only have the epoch data.

Comment: Pretty sure someone has already made an epoch to date library.

Comment: [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/213c8bc0f61a1a84) shows that `localtime` is actually the issue.  Not sure why though but figured that would help.

Comment: `char* buffer` is an uninitialized buffer, so it will crash when you `strftime` to that. `char buffer[80]` at least gives you something to work with. Look at things like [`std::ctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) for formatting. That value is also in nanoseconds, not seconds, which is out of the range of `time_t`. Try dividing by 1000000000. The current time is now `1499366981` and `time_t` is a 32-bit signed number.

Comment: @Idle001 I have already done my research and have been working on this problem for a sufficient amount of time to merit coming here to ask. The solution I show above is the result of my research; that %j is the only premade conversion library I found for day of the year. I found it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/ if that helps at all.

Comment: @Jhecht if you could point me in the right direction I would be grateful. I have only found this thus far: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/ plus the resource I already included in my question.

Comment: @NathanOliver that does help a lot actually, thank you. My debugger pinned it to the `strftime` line, but it looks like the problem was even deeper than that. Many thanks.

Comment: Which epoch? The UNIX epoch? Can't be as that seconds value is way too large.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it is the UNIX epoch. The answer I just marked correct pointed out that the number must be in nanoseconds, which is correct. The data translator does not divide the timestamp by `pow(10,9)` which was actually not a bug in my code, but it was foolish for me to assume that it did.

Comment: @JosephFarah Your question says it is seconds. For future reference when saying "epoch" you should specify which one. Epoch just means "some beginning" and there are basically an infinite number of epochs that could have been chosen; several are in common use (e.g. GPS epoch, TAI epoch)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks for the advice, noted. Sorry if my question is misleading, but that is what I thought it was. The answer marked correct provides the nanosecond solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact they're supposed to be epoch times, your timestamps are in nanoseconds.

`1498493536984926976s = 4.749E10 years`.

`1498493536984926976ns = 47.49 years`.

Unless your time stamps really are 34 billion years into the future, you should convert them to seconds before sending them to `localtime` to get a `struct tm`.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct for now, because it definitely gets me a lot closer to the right answer (returns a number in the 170s, which makes sense since the date should be in May or something). Thanks @Ics

Comment: [June 26th, 2017](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(January+1st+1970+EST)+%2B+1498493536984926976ns) according to Wolframalpha.

Comment: @Ics thanks, I should have checked that haha. That still is consistent with around the time the data was taken.

Comment: 47.49 is obviously near the middle of the year ;)

Answer (score 4):

These lines are your problem:

```
char *buffer;

strftime (buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%j",&date);
```

You've allocated a `char *` but it doesn't point to anything. It's just a random value, so you're passing a wild pointer into `strftime()`. Also, `sizeof(buffer)` will be the size of the pointer (4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture), not the size of the array that buffer is supposed to point at.

Change `char * buffer` to `char buffer[32];` or something like that.

Comment: The OP already said they changed `buffer` to be `char buffer[80]` and that did not help.  The `char *buffer;` is a red herring.

Comment: He hadn't said that when I wrote the answer. But he has said "My debugger pinned it to the strftime line".

Comment: Yes he did. That line has been in the Q the [entire time](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44956621/1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potential solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
  // Original value is a 64-bit unsigned integer representing the time in nanoseconds
  long long rawtime = 1498493536984926976LL;

  std::cout << rawtime << std::endl;

  // To convert from nanoseconds to seconds divide by a billion
  time_t epochtime = rawtime / 1000000000LL;
  std::cout << epochtime << std::endl;

  struct tm date;
  date = *std::localtime(&epochtime);

  // Uses a fixed-length buffer for `strtftime`
  char buffer[256];
  std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
  strftime(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%j",&date);

  std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Needs documenting comments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good point. Added a little context there.

Comment: That's lovely now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem here is that `localtime( &rawtime )` fails to convert `rawtime`.  When the function fails it returns a null pointer.  Dereferencing that pointer and trying to copy its value is causing the segfault.

The most likely issue is that your value is much to large.  If you do

```
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::cout << t << std::endl;
```

You get

```
1499367157
```

Which makes `1498493536984926976` a date in the way far future.

Comment: Notice the prefix, though. It's a 64-bit high precision time value.

Comment: @tadman Sorry I had a error with my code block.  Is the comment still relevant and if so can you elaborate more?

Comment: What is 1499367157 times a billion? It's suspiciously close to that value you're assuming is in the distant future.

Comment: @tadman The op says `1498493536984926976` is seconds.  If that's true then it is in the far future.  So either the OP missread what the data actually represents or the date is in the distant future.

Comment: That time is either June 26, 2017 or August 30, 47,485,371,817. The more plausible soluton, as confirmed by the asker, is it's nanoseconds. Nobody is making appointments after the sun has expanded to consume the Earth in around 8 billion years.

Answer (score 1):

And here it is using [Howard Hinnant's free, open source date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    std::istringstream file{"1498493536984926976"};
    std::int64_t i;
    file >> i;
    std::cout << format("%j\n", sys_time<nanoseconds>{nanoseconds{i}});
}
```

Output:

```
177
```

Notes:

- You don't specify, but I assumed "seconds from the Epoch" meant UTC.  Once you start calling things like `localtime`, you are bringing your computer's local time zone offset into the computation.  My code above keeps everything in UTC.
- Once the `int` is parsed from the file, the formatting is a one-liner, with no explicit conversion factors.
- If you need the day of the year as an `int`, instead of streamed out, that is also easily accomplished:

>

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    std::istringstream file{"1498493536984926976"};
    std::int64_t i;
    file >> i;
    auto sd = floor<days>(sys_time<nanoseconds>{nanoseconds{i}});
    auto y = year_month_day{sd}.year();
    int doy = (sd - sys_days{y/jan/1}).count() + 1;
    std::cout << doy << '\n';
}
```

In this latter case, the nanoseconds-precision `time_point` is truncated to a `time_point` with a precision of `days`.  That truncated `time_point` is then converted to a `year_month_day` object for the purpose of extracting the current `year` (using UTC).  And finally the first day of that year is subtracted from the truncated `time_point`, resulting in a `chrono::duration` with a precision of `days`.  1 is added to the result because `%j` specifies that Jan 1 is day 1.

The output is again:

```
177
```